# Reading data from Simulink into Python over UDP

Tags: python, udp, simulink

I want to send data from a Simulink model (running in real time) to a Python script (also running in real time.  I am using Simulink's built-in "UDP Send" block, which works, but I don't know how to decode the data I'm getting.  This is what my python script looks like:

```
import sys, struct
from socket import *

SIZE = 1024      # packet size

hostName = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')

mySocket  = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind((hostName,5002))

repeat = True
while repeat:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    data = struct.unpack('d',data)
    print data
```

I've suspected that the data stream should be something like a double, but while it's giving me numbers they aren't meaningful:

- If simulink sends a constant "1", I get an output of "3.16e-322"
- If Simulink sends a constant "2", I get an output of "3.038e-319"

Any ideas?

Comment: @ user1636547 here 5002 is which port no?  for my script which port no i have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my network was reversing the packet bits.  The solution was to read it in as bit-reversed:

```
data = struct.unpack('!d',data)
```

I have no clue why this happens over some networks and not others.  Can someone comment on a way to tell if I need to use bit-reversal?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the sender and receiver has different byte order.
See sys.byteorder.
Best practice should be to always convert to network order when sending and convert again when receiving.